# ng-show, ng-hide is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

`ng-show` and `ng-hide` are not working properly. In my controller I have
**`$scope.isHide=true`**; It is working. But `$scope` is not updating when it changes the value inside the nested function. Code description is as follows,

```
 $scope.isHide=true //It works

  $scope.productdetails = function (size,selectedproduct)
     {
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: '/Selection_Routing/Selection_Product/ProductDetails.html',
        controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, product) {
            $scope.product = product;

            $scope.buy = function (path) {
                $uibModalInstance.close($scope.product);
                $location.path(path);
                $scope.isHide= false; // Not working
            };

        },            
    });
};
```

Comment: Yeah I tried like this. $scope.isHide= false; $scope.$apply(). Doesn't work.

Comment: What's going on with $location.path(path)? It looks like your losing the context of $scope with a route change.

Comment: Depending on your route config `$location.path(path);` could be destroying the controller itself.

Comment: Yeah, That could be the reason. What would be the possible solution then?

Comment: If you need to persist state between route changes consider adding a service to hold the state.

Comment: @Rubel what would be the solution? First of all explain why you are doing it   ? Especially in the middle of a function execution?

Comment: $rootScope.showcarousel = true; and $rootScope.showcarousel = false; are working....

Comment: @Rubel if you have to use `$rootScope` for something silly that means there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: @T J: Acutally from a product details modal I want to redirect to the shopping cart page that is why I applied $location.path(path); and when it is redirecting to shopping cart page I want to hide carousel from the page...That is the reason....

Answer (score 0):

I think what you miss here is to pass the current $scope to your modal,

Please try the following:

```
 $scope.isHide=true;

 $scope.productdetails = function (size,selectedproduct)
 {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl:   '/Selection_Routing/Selection_Product/ProductDetails.html',
    scope: $scope, //passed current scope to the modal
    controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, product) {
        $scope.product = product;

        $scope.buy = function (path) {
            $uibModalInstance.close($scope.product);
            $location.path(path);
            $scope.isHide= false;
        };

    },            
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if binded property is a object instead a primitive its works

```
$scope.isHide= {value:true};

 $scope.productdetails = function (size,selectedproduct)
 {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl:   '/Selection_Routing/Selection_Product/ProductDetails.html',
    scope: $scope, //passed current scope to the modal
    controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, product) {
        $scope.product = product;

        $scope.buy = function (path) {
            $uibModalInstance.close($scope.product);
            $location.path(path);
            $scope.isHide.value= false;
        };

    },            
});
};
```